# Tangent space to the intersection of two manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, manifolds

Let $M, N \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be two manifolds such that, for every $p \in M \cap N$, $(T_pM)^\bot \cap (T_pN)^\bot = \{0\}$.

How do I determine the tangent space of $M \cap N$? I found some places which stated that the tangent space to the intersection is the intersection of the tangent spaces, but I think that there is a little bit more to it due to the condition on the intersection of the orthogonal spaces.

Any hints?

Comment: Clearly the tangent space of the intersection is always a *subspace* of the intersection of the tangent spaces. Presumably in your case you can set up slice charts to show that the two spaces are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the condition implies that

$$ \{ 0 \} = (T_pM)^{\perp} \cap (T_pN)^{\perp} = (T_pM + T_pN)^{\perp} $$

and so $T_pM + T_pN = T_p(\mathbb{R}^n) \approx \mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, we say that the subspaces (and if it holds for all $p \in M \cap N$, the manifolds) **intersect transversally**. Using the implicit function theorem, you can show that this condition guarantees that the intersection $M \cap N$ is indeed a submanifold of dimension $\dim T_pM \cap T_pN$ and with tangent space $T_pM \cap T_pN$. Without this condition, it is not in general true that the intersection $M \cap N$ is even a manifold.